# Existence of polynomials so that inequality holds

Tags: analysis, inequality, polynomials, convergence-divergence

Is there a polynomial $P$ such that $|P^2(x)-e^{10x}|<10^{10} \text{ for each }  x\in \mathbb{R} ?$

Is there a polynomial $Q$ such that $|Q^2(x)-e^{10x}|<10^{-10} \text{ for each } x \in [0,1] ?$

I have thought the following: We look at the convergence of $e^{10x}$.

The exponential function is continuous.

I have thought to calculate the supremum of $e^{10x}$ in the given intervals. And then we would look if there is a polynomial function so that the difference of the exponential function and the polynomial tends to $0$ in these intervals.

Is my approach right?

Comment: There is a well known series expansion for $e^x$ which is absolutely convergent to $e^x$, now use sufficient number of terms in that series to get the desired error bounds. This is for the second question. For the first one, consider the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} p(x)/e^x$ for some polynomial $p$, which I guess you can evaluateby repeatedly using L'Hospital's rule...

Comment: You mean that we use the fact that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$, right?

Comment: Yes Yes Yes Yes... :) (There is a minimum character length for a comment)

Comment: So for the first inequality, we take a polynomial $p(x)=a_k x^k+\dots+a_0$. Then using De l'Hospital, we get that $\frac{p^2(x)}{e^{10x}}=\dots \frac{const.}{10^r e^{10r}}$ and this tends to $0$ for $r$ big enough. So for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $n_0$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0, |p^2(x)-e^{10x}|<\epsilon$. We pick $\epsilon=10^{10}$. Is this right?

Comment: It's quite the opposite, give it another shot. The limit that you are evaluating is $p^2(x)/e^x$. How did it suddenly become $|p^2(x)-e^x|$ in the last line? Eidt: You have to excuse me, I keep missing the $10x$

Comment: @Krishnarjun And for the first, we say that we pick a sufficient number of terms in that series to get the desired error bounds. But the series inf not of the form $\text{polynomial}^2$. How can we get this form? We cannot take the square because then maybe it won't remain a polynomial.

Comment: Ah! yes, that is a valid question. But there are many polynomials which are aribitrarily close to any continuous function. Therefore, it should be true that there is a square of a polynomial which satisfies your given condition. But I have to think for a bit. If I get something, I will spell it out here. Cheers...

Comment: @Krishnarjun So for the first we get that $\left| \frac{P^2(x)}{e^{10x}}\right|<\epsilon$.How do we proceed ? Do we use the triangular inequality?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118917/discussion-between-krishnarjun-and-pingu).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first one is negative.
Since $P^2(x)$ is a polynomial and $e^{10x}$ is an exponential function, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}{(e^{10x}-P^2(x))}=\infty$.
On the other hand the answer to the second problem is clearly positive since the existance of such $Q$ is equivalent to :
$$-e^{-10}-10^{-10}<Q^2(x)<1+10^{-10}$$
Now take any arbitrary polynomial $P$ and there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (sufficiently big) such that $Q(x)=\frac{P(x)}{c}$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: For the second inequality, We have that $1<e^{10x}<e^{10}$, right? @AryanHemmati From $|Q^2(x)-e^{10x}|<10^{-10}$ we gat that $-10^{-10}<Q^2(x)-e^{10x}<10^{-10}$. Then we get $e^{10x}-10^{-10}<Q^2(x)<e^{10x}+10^{-10} \Rightarrow 1-10^{-10}<Q^2(x)<e^{10}+10^{-10}$. Is it right like that?

Comment: Exactly! Those are the points $e^{10x}$ reaches its max and min for $x\in [0,1]$

Comment: And why will $\frac{P(x)}{c}$ satify this condition? How do we choose $P$ and $c$ ? @AryanHemmati

Comment: Since the LHS is negative and $Q^2(x)$ is positive, it suffices that $Q^2(x)$ is always less than a constant value for $x\in [0,1]$. Hence if you choose polynomial $P(x)$ arbitrarily, for sufficiently big $c$, $\frac{P(x)}{c}$ the upper bound will hold.